# How to create an object like `()` in user space

Tags: julia

In Julia the empty tuple is both a type and an instance of that type. So `isa((),())` is `true`. Is it possible to create a similar object myself?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe so.  In fact, in Julia 0.4 `isa((),())` is no longer true.  The type of `()` is now `Tuple{}`:

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.0-dev+5441"

julia> typeof(())
Tuple{}

julia> isa((),()) # Throws an error since () is no longer considered a Type
ERROR: TypeError: isa: expected Type{T}, got Tuple{}
```

I think the only remaining objects that are an instance of themselves are `Any`, `Type` and `DataType`.

Comment: Heh, I was hoping that it would be possible to trick the system by setting `abstract Foo; Foo.super = Foo` ... This doesn't have any effect though, because ultimately the `isa` check goes through `jl_subtype_le` which has a special-case for `jl_any`.